# Столкнулся с проблемой при обучении, как создать число Фибоначчи N 0,1,1,2,3,5,8.... в массиве с циклом While

Tags: c#, массивы, while, числа-фибоначчи

while- реализовать задачу используя массыв и методы

- int[] GetFibonacciWithWhile(int number)

код :

```
class Program
{
    static uint[] GetFibonacciWithWhile(uint n)
    {
        uint[] arr = new uint[n];
        n = 1;
        arr[0] = 0; 
        arr[1] = 1;
        arr[2] = 1;           
        
        while (n > 1)
        {
            n++;
            arr[n] = arr[1] + arr[2];
        }
        return arr;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("F = ");
        var n = Convert.ToUInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine($"{n} числа последовательности Фибоначчи");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", GetFibonacciWithWhile(n)));
        GetFibonacciWithWhile(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ладно, в чем проблема то? Пытались сами что-то решить или предлагаете нам тут за вас все сделать?

Comment: да пытался !в цикле видно ошибка не могу понять

Answer (score 0):

Ответ прост как и вопрос.
Функция фибоначи

1. Рекурсия. Если N = 1 тогда верните 1
   иначе если N < 1 верните 0
   иначе фибоначи для предыдушего N плюс фибоначи за педыдушего предыдещего N
2. Цикл. Идея другая, но результат тот же

Удачи.

Я вижу был добавлен код.
исправьте тут.

```
for (i = 2 ; i < n ; i++)
{
 arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2];
}
```

и не используйте переменную переданную в ф-и

Comment: Тут подойдет обычный for цикл. Кстати в вашем цикле while 2 ошибки. `i < n`, `i++;` нужно подвинуть в конец.

Comment: @tim32167 так лучше?

Comment: Индекс 2 у автора уже заполнен, вы можете начать с 3, но вцелом да, гораздо лучше.

Comment: @tym32167  Понятно что for подойдет ,но задача стоит реализовать с помощью  while

Comment: они идентичны можешь реализовать через while